# Change the name of the field in WebAPI Odata in ODataModelBuilder

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api

I have class with properties and I want to show diffrent property name in the webAPI.
For example DeploymentTypeEnum in my class and in the odata I want to add it with name 
DeploymentType.

```
builder
.Entity<Product>()
.Property(c => c.DeploymentTypeEnum );
```

Comment: web API OData doesn't have support for that.

Comment: +1, did you find a way of doing it?